# Want to make a complex query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I have to remove data and count for facebbok like notification. there are 3 tables from where i need to remove data
1st company table where i remove company id.
2nd table is mark_question where i mark the question as read/unread, fav/unfav, notification status
3rd is the forum topic questions where the data regarding the questions asked

1st query is removed on the result of a query where i get a set of values.

```
select * 
       from gl_mark_ques 
       where user_id =".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and 
             vs_ques_status=0
```

after this i get a set of id's these id's should not be present in the next query i execute

```
SELECT uc.*,count(mq.vs_ques_status) 
       from gl_user_comp as uc 
       inner join gl_mark_ques as mq 
             on uc.user_id=mq.user_id and 
                uc.comp_id='$comp_id' 
       where mq.user_id<>".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and 
             mq.new_ques_id!=2 and 
             mq.vs_ques_status=1
```

mq.new_ques_id=2 <-- here i need to add the id's i got from first query. There may be only one id or multiple id's. How do  i integrate this kindly help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT uc.*,count(mq.vs_ques_status) as cnt_status_advhub 
from gl_user_comp as uc inner join gl_mark_ques as mq 
on uc.user_id=mq.user_id and uc.comp_id='$comp_id' 
where mq.user_id<>".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and 
mq.vs_ques_status=1 and mq.new_ques_id NOT IN 
(select new_ques_id from gl_mark_ques where user_id 
=".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and vs_ques_status=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the ids from the 1st query be removed from the 2nd query why don't you add the negated part of the 1st WHERE as an AND in the 2nd query?

```
AND (user_id !=".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." or vs_ques_status!=0)
```

I don't fully understand your problem, but, in any case you can create a subquery and apply NOT IN (SELECT ...) in the WHERE...

Comment: The ids that i get from the query : `select * 
       from gl_mark_ques 
       where user_id =".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and 
             vs_ques_status=0` should not be present in the next query 'where new_ques_id!=id(from previous query)'

Comment: Try: `SELECT uc.*,count(mq.vs_ques_status) 
       from gl_user_comp as uc 
       inner join gl_mark_ques as mq 
             on uc.user_id=mq.user_id and 
                uc.comp_id='$comp_id' 
       where mq.user_id<>".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and 
             mq.new_ques_id!=2 and 
             mq.vs_ques_status=1
and mq.new_ques_id NOT IN (select ques_id from gl_mark_ques where user_id =".$this->session->userdata('user_id')." and vs_ques_status=0)`